# can you reduce this macro run time from current 8 minutes?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

My team generates files from webscraping where *one of the columns* is **company name**, but the source doesn't *normalize*, so the values *end* in things like `Pvt. Ltd., Pvt. Ltd, Pvt Ltd., Co., Corp., Corporation`, etc., but these variants must be removed for the next step in our process.

My macro works, but it takes literally 8 minutes to run on the one Company column with 1626 typical records. I know the problem is related to how many replacements and loops I'm doing, and I've read about things like:

```
Dim xArray As Variant
xArray = Array(" -*", " (*", " –*", " ,*", ", *", "No Experienced Listed")
For Each cell In Selection
    temp = cell.Value
    If InStr(1, temp, xArray) > 0 Then ' << BUT this line is generating Type Mismatch error - WHY?
        cell.Value = Replace(temp, xArray, "")
    End If
Next
```

But I don't know if the above (even if you told me how to fix) would noticeably help.

What's a *more efficient way* to code the macro below?

```
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

MsgBox ("Please wait up to 8 minutes for macro to complete after clicking OK button. Ignore any Excel Not Responding warning atop screen or slowly spinning icon in middle of screen.")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In Selection
    cell.Value = Trim(cell)
    temp = cell.Value
    cell.Value = StrConv(temp, vbProperCase)
Next

For Each cell In Selection
    If InStr(cell, " -") > 0 Then  'get rid of space hyphen and anything after
       cell.Replace " -*", ""
    End If
    If InStr(cell, " ,") > 0 Then  'get rid of comma and anything after
        cell.Replace ",*", ""
    End If
    If InStr(cell, " (") > 0 Then  'get rid of space left paren and anything after
        cell.Replace " (*", ""
    End If
    If cell.Value = "No Experience Listed" Then  'clear cell
        cell.Value = ""
    End If
Next

'reduced number of replacements needed below via strTextProperCase = StrConv(strText, vbProperCase)
'inserted above per https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/upper-lower-proper-case-functions/
For Each cell In Selection
    If cell <> "" Then cell.Value = Trim(cell)
        If Left(cell, 4) = "The " Then cell.Value = Right(cell, Len(cell) - 4)
        If Right(cell, 5) = " Inc." Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 5)
        If Right(cell, 4) = " Inc" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 4)
        If Right(cell, 8) = " Pvt.Ltd" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 8)
        If Right(cell, 10) = " Pvt. Ltd." Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 10)
        If Right(cell, 9) = " Pvt. Ltd" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 9)
        If Right(cell, 9) = " Pvt Ltd." Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 9)
        If Right(cell, 8) = " Pvt Ltd" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 7)
        If Right(cell, 5) = " Pvt." Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 5)
        If Right(cell, 4) = " Pvt" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 4)
        If Right(cell, 7) = " L.L.C." Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 7)
        If Right(cell, 8) = " Private" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 8)
        If Right(cell, 5) = " Ltd." Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 5)
        If Right(cell, 4) = " Ltd" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 4)
        If Right(cell, 4) = " LLC" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 4)
        If Right(cell, 6) = ", L.P." Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 6)
        If Right(cell, 5) = " B.V." Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 5)
        If Right(cell, 5) = " L.P." Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 5)
        If Right(cell, 4) = " Llp" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 4)
        If Right(cell, 3) = " Lp" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 3)
        If Right(cell, 12) = " Corporation" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 12)
        If Right(cell, 6) = " Corp." Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 6)
        If Right(cell, 8) = " Limited" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 8)
        If Right(cell, 6) = " & Co." Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 6)
        If Right(cell, 5) = " & Co" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 5)
        If Right(cell, 4) = " Co." Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 4)
        If Right(cell, 3) = " Co" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 3)
        If Right(cell, 3) = " Ag" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 3)
        If Right(cell, 10) = " Companies" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 10)
        If Right(cell, 8) = " Company" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 8)
        If Right(cell, 13) = " Incorporated" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 13)
        If Right(cell, 3) = " In" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 3)
        If Right(cell, 3) = " Lt" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 3)
        If Right(cell, 3) = " Ag" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 3)
        If Right(cell, 2) = " S" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 3)
        If Right(cell, 4) = " B.V" Then cell.Value = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 4)
Next

End If
Application.Goto Reference:=ws.Range("B1")
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, you can make this more efficient.  Please **EDIT** your question to post a representative data sample (doesn't have to be real data) **AS TEXT** which can be copy pasted, and perhaps a screenshot of the desired results from that sample data.

Comment: And your type mismatch on the Instr function is because the third argument is expecting a string, and you are using a Variant Array

Comment: Read the cell value *once* into a variable, instead of reading each cell dozens of times

Comment: Posted a possible approach how to condense information in an efficient way (referring also to @TimWilliams ' valuable comment).

Answer (score 0):

**How to gain efficiency**

- Looping through cells by means of vba is time consuming: assign the relevant column to a (1) datafield array & (2) loop through the elements eventually.
- Split the company informations into tokens.
- Structure your code and break it down into the necessary steps; essentially you want to remove (2a) articles in the first token, (2b) company suffixes in the last token as well as (2c) possible prefixes like `Private, Pvt` etc. This can be done via help procedure `mark` in only three steps - thus you avoid to read each cell value dozens of times
  (see Tim's valuable comment).
- (2d:e) Change the array elements with the condensed company infos and
- (3) Write the entire array back to the original range (or a neighbouring column when testing).

The following procedure should give you an idea how to procede
*(possible example call: `Condense Sheet1.Range("A2:A6000")`)*

```
Sub Condense(rng As Range)
'0. Definitions
    Dim articles As String: articles = "The La (No)"
    Dim corps As String: corps = "Ltd Corporation comp company (Listed)"
    Dim privs As String: privs = "Pvt Pvt. Private (Experience)"
'1. Get data
    Dim data As Variant
    data = rng.Resize(, 1).Value    ' accept only 1st column
'2. Loop through data and mark tokens to be removed
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
        Dim tokens As Variant
        tokens = Split(data(i, 1))
        
        '2a) Mark articles in first token
        mark tokens, 0, articles
        '2b) Mark corporations in last token
        Dim last As Long
        last = UBound(tokens)
        mark tokens, last, corps
        '2c) Mark possible corporation prefix Private etc.
        If last - 1 Then
            mark tokens, last - 1, privs
        End If
        
        '2d) Remove marked tokens via negative filtering
        tokens = Filter(tokens, "%DEL%", False)
        '2e) Join condensed elements
        data(i, 1) = Join(tokens)
     Next i
 '3. Write results
     rng.Offset(, 0) = data   ' or any other column offset for testing 
End Sub
```

```
Sub mark(tokens, ByVal tokenIndex As Long, list)
    Const Del  As String = "%DEL%"
    Dim token  As String: token = tokens(tokenIndex)
    Dim delims As Variant: delims = Split(". , - ( )")
    Dim delim  As Variant
    For Each delim In delims
        token = Replace(token, delim, "")   ' delete delimiters
    Next
    If InStr(1, list, token, vbTextCompare) Then
        tokens(tokenIndex) = Del            ' mark tokens found in list
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome. Could be optimized even further by building a dictionary or collection object so that you can match against a set of values via an internal hashmap rather than matching vs the corps and privs arrays.

Comment: Based on the comment by JSmart523, I'm guessing T.M.'s answer is a solution, but after I create the Condense and mark macros (both have Sub and End Sub, VBA didn't show any errors when I added them to the same project/.xlsb file as my original macro), neither one appears as a selectable choice to run, and generally this level of VB is above my skillset, so I'm guessing I'm missing something. I hope to learn enough Excel VBA someday in order to work with this.

Comment: @GlennGutmacher So what's the problem (without "any errors") - don't you get any output, do you miss something in output? Would appreciate a more detailed response where you are confronted with issues or code parts you find difficult to understand. This would be helpful for any other contributors/readers, too. - Did you use the 100% identical code, where did you modify it? Of course it would be necessary to extend the sample company definitions.

Comment: @GlennGutmacher I tested it with up to 10000 rows and it run in 0.03 - 0.05 seconds. - As you mention an *.xlsb file* - did you try to  call `Condense` from another workbook, then try e.g.: `Application.Run "Personal.xlsb!Condense", Sheet1.Range("A2:A6000")` (or any other worksheet range reference)?
`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use regular expressions:

```
Sub ClearTextsRE()
    Dim myRegExp As Object, cl As Range
    Set myRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    With myRegExp
        .Pattern = "Ltd\.|\WAg\W|\WLt\W|The |Inc\.|Limited |& Co\.|Corporation|Incorporated|Private|Pvt\.| +|,+|-+" 'and so on
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
    End With
    
    For Each cl In Selection
        cl.Offset(, 1) = Trim(myRegExp.Replace(cl, " "))
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I added some more regex values to replace & this still worked. The only problem is for cases where the company name ends in space Ag, space Lt, or similar short corporate suffixes that can appear within other legit company names. Unfortunately, it also removes that short string from within legit words, too (e.g., Ansys Innagada turns into Ansys Inn ada). I'm only worried about where company cell ENDS in a space + corporate suffix. How do I modify your regex to address?

Comment: @GlennGutmacher code updated (using `\WAg\W|\WLt\W`). [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4QQTMh/1)